# Unable to train from flow_from_dataframe Got unexpected no. of classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am going to train a model on the set of images whose labels are in a csv file. So I used `flow_from_dataframe from tf.keras` and specified the parameters, but when it comes to `class_mode` it says errors and says `Found 3662 validated image filenames belonging to 1 classes.` - for both sparse and categorical. This is multi class classification."

"Initially labels were int so i converted it to strings then I got this output."

```
df_train=pd.read_csv(r"../input/train.csv",delimiter=',')
df_test=pd.read_csv(r"../input/test.csv",delimiter=',')
print(df_train.head())
print(df_test.head())
df_train['id_code']=df_train['id_code']+'.png'
df_train['diagnosis']=str(df_train['diagnosis'])
df_test['id_code']=df_test['id_code']+'.png'

""" output is
        id_code  diagnosis
0  000c1434d8d7          2
1  001639a390f0          4
2  0024cdab0c1e          1
3  002c21358ce6          0
4  005b95c28852          0
        id_code
0  0005cfc8afb6
1  003f0afdcd15
2  006efc72b638
3  00836aaacf06
4  009245722fa4
"""

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range=30,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

TRAINING_DIR='../input/train_images'

train_generator= train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_train,
    directory=TRAINING_DIR,
    x_col='id_code',
    y_col='diagnosis',
    batch_size=20,
    target_size=(1050,1050),
    class_mode='categorical'#used also sparsed
)

""" output is
Found 3662 validated image filenames belonging to 1 classes.
"""
```

“I expect the output of `"Found 3662 validated image filenames belonging to 5 classes"` , but the actual output is `"Found 3662 validated image filenames belonging to 1 classes"`

”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"sparse" class mode requires integer value and "categorical" requires one hot encoded vector of your class columns. So I would try:

```
df['diagnosis'] = df['diagnosis'].astype(str)
```

and then use "sparse" class mode.

```
train_generator= train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_train,
    directory=TRAINING_DIR,
    x_col='id_code',
    y_col='diagnosis',
    batch_size=20,
    target_size=(1050,1050),
    class_mode='sparse'
)
```

Or **alternatively** you can use **one hot encoding** like this:

```
pd.get_dummies(df,prefix=['diagnosis'], drop_first=True)
```

And then use "categorical" class_mode:

```
train_generator= train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df_train,
    directory=TRAINING_DIR,
    x_col='id_code',
    y_col=df.columns[1:],
    batch_size=20,
    target_size=(1050,1050),
    class_mode='categorical'
)
```

Comment: what about using "category" dtype for pandas columns ? And the alternative solution that I just provide ?

Comment: when using df_train['diagnosis']=df_train.astype({'diagnosis': 'category'}) I got Found 3662 validated image filenames belonging to 3662 classes. and when using pd.get_dummies(df_train,prefix=['diagnosis'], drop_first=True) I got TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="Index(['diagnosis'], dtype='object')" column values must be type string, list or tuple. @Simon Delecourt

Comment: Thanks to you I searched google for astype and i found astype(str) and i applied it to  my code like df_train['diagnosis']=df_train['diagnosis'].astype(str) and got the desired result. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Can you please accept it as answer as it covers 2 ways to handle your problem. Thanks

Comment: @SimonDelecourt In the second method, the error `TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="Index(['diagnosis'], dtype='object')" column values must be type string, list or tuple` can be resolved by setting `y_col = list(df.columns[1:])` but still another error occurs `TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="['class_0', 'class_1', ... ]" column values must be type string, list or tuple.
`

Comment: @SimonDelecourt the error in the second approach has also been asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339566/flow-from-dataframe-with-multiple-column-names-fed-into-y-col-generates-type-err

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To @Simon Delecourt I got the answer to the question.

I used

```
df_train['diagnosis']=df_train['diagnosis'].astype(str)
```

in converting the datatype of the column `diagnosis` to str

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if one hot encoding will help ...as when class_mode is set to "categorical", flow_from_dataframe() automatically performs one-hot encoding on the target variable specified in y_col.