# Flow from dataframe with multiple column names fed into y_col generates TYPE ERROR

Tags: keras

I am using flow from data frame for a multi-label classification problem with 14 possible labels, all column names are placed in a list in string format for example:

```
columns = ["No Finding", "Enlarged Cardiomediastinum", "Cardiomegaly", "Lung Opacity", "Lung      Lesion","Edema", "Consolidation", "Pneumonia", "Atelectasis", "Pneumothorax", "Pleural Effusion", "Pleural Other", "Fracture", "Support Devices"]
```

The list name (columns) is then fed into y_col for example:

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df[:178731],
directory='/home/admin1/Downloads/',
x_col='Path',
y_col=columns,
batch_size=batch_size,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
target_size=(224, 224))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: If class_mode="categorical", y_col="['No Finding', 'Enlarged Cardiomediastinum', 'Cardiomegaly', 'Lung Opacity', 'Lung Lesion', 'Edema', 'Consolidation', 'Pneumonia', 'Atelectasis', 'Pneumothorax', 'Pleural Effusion', 'Pleural Other', 'Fracture', 'Support Devices']" column values must be type string, list or tuple.
```

I have already tried the solution previously proposed:

```
df['No Finding'] = df['No Finding'].astype(str)
df['Enlarged Cardiomediastinum'] = df['Enlarged Cardiomediastinum'].astype(str)
df['Cardiomegaly'] = df['Cardiomegaly'].astype(str)
df['Lung Opacity'] = df['Lung Opacity'].astype(str)
df['Lung Lesion'] = df['Lung Lesion'].astype(str)
df['Edema'] = df['Edema'].astype(str)
df['Consolidation'] = df['Consolidation'].astype(str)
df['Pneumonia'] = df['Pneumonia'].astype(str)
df['Atelectasis'] = df['Atelectasis'].astype(str)
df['Pneumothorax'] = df['Pneumothorax'].astype(str)
df['Pleural Effusion'] = df['Pleural Effusion'].astype(str)
df['Pleural Other'] = df['Pleural Other'].astype(str)
df['Fracture'] = df['Fracture'].astype(str)
df['Support Devices'] = df['Support Devices'].astype(str)
```

It only works when I'm feeding a single column name to y_col. I'm using keras 2.2.4 and I have already uninstalled keras.preprocessing and installed the github version. It seems that the flow from directory function does not support multiple column names being fed to y_col in list format using the default class mode as categorical since this is a muti-label classification problem. I suspect that the type issue stems from pandas dataframes values only being converted to objects and the keras preprocessing dataframe iterator code only allows string, list or tuple but pandas does not directly convert to string only to object. Below is my code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('/home/admin1/Downloads/CheXpert-v1.0/train.csv')

df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
df['No Finding'].head()

df['No Finding'] = df['No Finding'].astype(str)
df['Enlarged Cardiomediastinum'] = df['Enlarged Cardiomediastinum'].astype(str)
df['Cardiomegaly'] = df['Cardiomegaly'].astype(str)
df['Lung Opacity'] = df['Lung Opacity'].astype(str)
df['Lung Lesion'] = df['Lung Lesion'].astype(str)
df['Edema'] = df['Edema'].astype(str)
df['Consolidation'] = df['Consolidation'].astype(str)
df['Pneumonia'] = df['Pneumonia'].astype(str)
df['Atelectasis'] = df['Atelectasis'].astype(str)
df['Pneumothorax'] = df['Pneumothorax'].astype(str)
df['Pleural Effusion'] = df['Pleural Effusion'].astype(str)
df['Pleural Other'] = df['Pleural Other'].astype(str)
df['Fracture'] = df['Fracture'].astype(str)
df['Support Devices'] = df['Support Devices'].astype(str)
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(str)

df.dtypes

columns=["No Finding", "Enlarged Cardiomediastinum", "Cardiomegaly", "Lung Opacity",
"Lung Lesion","Edema", "Consolidation", "Pneumonia", "Atelectasis",
"Pneumothorax", "Pleural Effusion", "Pleural Other", "Fracture",
"Support Devices"]

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df[:178731],
directory='/home/admin1/Downloads/',
x_col='Path',
y_col=columns,
batch_size=batch_size,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
target_size=(224, 224))
```

Comment: I have added object to the type list in the preprocessing file but now I get a KEY ERROR:  KeyError: ['No Finding', 'Enlarged Cardiomediastinum', 'Cardiomegaly', 'Lung Opacity', 'Lung Lesion', 'Edema', 'Consolidation', 'Pneumonia', 'Atelectasis', 'Pneumothorax', 'Pleural Effusion', 'Pleural Other', 'Fracture', 'Support Devices']

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue and was able to solve it by changing the class_mode parameter to 'other'. I ran across [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24) after following a few links in the tensorflow documentation for flow_from_dataframe().

So based on what you have above, you only need to directly set your class_mode to 'other' and it should work.

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df[:178731],
directory='/home/admin1/Downloads/',
x_col='Path',
y_col=columns,
batch_size=batch_size,
class_mode='raw'
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
target_size=(224, 224))
```

I should say though, that I have have seen no mention of the class_mode 'other' in either the tensorflow or keras documentation. However, it does seem to work so I am running with it for now.

Edit: I have since realized that 'other' is depreciated in current versions of keras. I have updated the code above to reflect the new correct class_mode which should be 'raw'.

Answer (score 0):

`flow_from_dataframe` gets weird when using multiple column names in y_col -- especially when using 'categorical' class_mode.

The solution I found was to pre-combine all of my intended columns into a single combined column with Pandas before passing it into flow_from_dataframe so that I can pass a single column name into `flow_from_dataframe`.

````
columns = ["No Finding", "Enlarged Cardiomediastinum", "Cardiomegaly", "Lung Opacity", "Lung Lesion","Edema", "Consolidation", "Pneumonia", "Atelectasis", "Pneumothorax", "Pleural Effusion", "Pleural Other", "Fracture", "Support Devices"]

dataframe["CombinedColumns"] = dataframe[classes].apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df[:178731],
    directory='/home/admin1/Downloads/',
    x_col='Path',
    y_col="CombinedColumns",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(224, 224))```
````